# how to edit all text values in html tags using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

**What I want:** I am new to `Jsoup`. I want to parse my `html` string and search for each text value that appears inside tags (any tag). And then change that text value to something else.

**What I have done:** I am able to change the text value for single tag. Below is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<div><p>Test Data</p> <p>HELLO World</p></div>";
        Document doc1=Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements ps = doc1.getElementsByTag("p");
        for (Element p : ps) {
          String pText = p.text();
          p.text(base64_Dummy(pText));
        }
        System.out.println("======================");
        String changedHTML=doc1.html();
        System.out.println(changedHTML);
    }

    public static String base64_Dummy(String abc){
        return "This is changed text";
    }
```

**output:**

```
======================
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p>This is changed text</p> 
   <p>This is changed text</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Above code is able to change the `p` tag's value. But, in my case `html` string can contain any tag; whose value I want to search and change.
How can I search all tags in html string and change their text value one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with something similar to this code:

```
String html = "<html><body><div><p>Test Data</p> <div> <p>HELLO World</p></div></div> other text</body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
List<Node> children = doc.childNodes();

// We will search nodes in a breadth-first way
Queue<Node> nodes = new ArrayDeque<>();

nodes.addAll(doc.childNodes());

while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
    Node n = nodes.remove();

    if (n instanceof TextNode && ((TextNode) n).text().trim().length() > 0) {
        // Do whatever you want with n.
        // Here we just print its text...
        System.out.println(n.parent().nodeName()+" contains text: "+((TextNode) n).text().trim());
    } else {
        nodes.addAll(n.childNodes());
    }
}
```

And you'll get the following output:

```
body contains text: other text
p contains text: Test Data
p contains text: HELLO World
```

Comment: Sure, you can use `LinkedList` too.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the CSS selector `*` and the method `textNodes` to get the text of a given tag (`Element` in Jsoup world).

This line below

```
Elements ps = doc1.getElementsByTag("p");
```

becomes

```
Elements ps = doc1.select("*");
```

Now, with this new selector you'll be able to select any elements (tags) within your HTML code.

#### FULL CODE EXAMPLE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Setup proxy...");
    JSoup.setupProxy();

    String html = "<html><body><div><p>Test Data</p> <div> <p>HELLO World</p></div></div> other text</body></html>";
    Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements tags = doc1.select("*");
    for (Element tag : tags) {
        for (TextNode tn : tag.textNodes()) {
            String tagText = tn.text().trim();

            if (tagText.length() > 0) {
                tn.text(base64_Dummy(tagText));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("======================");
    String changedHTML = doc1.html();
    System.out.println(changedHTML);
}

public static String base64_Dummy(String abc) {
    return "This is changed text";
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
======================
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p>This is changed text</p> 
   <div> 
    <p>This is changed text</p>
   </div>
  </div>This is changed text
 </body>
</html>
```